# AppleScript & Excel: setting range based on variables

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I am an AppleScript newbie, and have nearly finished putting together a script to take a spreadsheet and format it for import into a FileMaker database. This spreadsheet is a monthly statement of donors, from which I want to extract only the donations. Below the donation records there is some accounting info in some of my import columns that I need to remove in order to get a clean import of the data.

Here is the script in its entirety:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
activate
set theWorkbook to open workbook workbook file name "File Path"
--Open the file that contains the DonorId for all Donors

set theWorkbook to open workbook workbook file name "File Path"
--Open the Monthly Transaction Report

set myrange_1 to range ("A1:E4")
delete myrange_1

tell worksheet "Transaction Report" of active workbook
    set value of cell "A1" to "DonorID"
    autofit columns of range "A1:A100"
    set lastRow to ((count of rows of used range of active sheet) - 13)
    set myRange_2 to range ("A2:A" & lastRow) of active sheet
    set formula of myRange_2 to "=VLOOKUP($C$2:$C$100,'[Donor ID.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$60, 2, FALSE)"
    set value of cell "F1" to "Donation Method"
    set myRange_3 to range ("F2:F" & lastRow) of active sheet
    set formula of myRange_3 to "=IF(D2=\"\",\"Check\", IF(D2=\"CC\",\"Credit Card\", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(\"E\",D2)),\"EFT\",\"#N/A\")))"
    try
        set myRange_2 to find what "#N/A" look at whole with match case
    on error
        log ("No matches found")
    end try

    if (myRange_2 is not "") then
        display dialog "New Donor @ " & (get address of the cells of myRange_2)
    end if
    set myRange_4 to range ("A" & lastRow + 1)
    set myRange_5 to range ("F" & lastRow + 13) 
end tell
end tell
```

Everything works great, except that I can't find a way to use variables to set a range of cells to delete. This range is from column 1 through 5 from the lastRow +1 to lastRow +13. I tried setting a range based on "myRange_4:myRange_5", but I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any more code in the script that could be posted in your question? :)

Comment: Just edited and posted the whole script

Comment: So, just to clarify, you are now wanting to select all of the columns (and corresponding rows) between _A.lastRow+1_ and _F.lastRow+13_ but that range isn't being selected because only columns _A_ and _F_ are being selected at this point?

Comment: Yes, I want to select A.lastRow+1 and F.lastRow+13. When I try to     set myRange_6 to "myRange_4:myRange_5" and then Delete myRange_6, I get an error message.

Comment: Like this :   `set rangeToDelete to range ("A" & (lastRow + 1)) & “:F” & ( lastRow + 13)`

Comment: @jackjr300 please make that into an answer for the OP to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution

```
set rangeToDelete to range ("A" & (lastRow + 1)) & “:F” & ( lastRow + 13)
```